# Batch Processing - Odata

Tags: json, odata

I want to make requests to allow grouping of multiple operations into a single HTTP request payload

I have an API Key that allows me to make Get Requests and return tables in a Database as JSON blocks. Certain attributes are 'expandable' and OData (Open Data Protocol) allows you to 'expand' multiple attributes within the "CompanyA" table (ie Marketing, Sales, HR)

```
http://api.blahblah.com/odata/CompanyA?apikey=b8blachblahblachc&$expand=Marketing,Sales,HR
```

I would like to select multiple tables, (the request above only contains 1 table which was Company A) and understand this is possible via "Batch Requests"

https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

The documentation above alongside Microsoft's is hard to translate into my noted desire.

I wanted it to be as simple as, but I know it is not and can't figure out how to get there:

```
http://api.blahblah.com/odata/CompanyA,CompanyB,CompanyC?apikey=b8blachblahblachc
```

The end goal is to have one JSON file that contains detail about each table in the DB , rather than have to write each individual query and save it file as below:

```
http://api.blahblah.com/odata/CompanyA?apikey=b8blachblahblachc
http://api.blahblah.com/odata/CompanyB?apikey=b8blachblahblachc
http://api.blahblah.com/odata/CompanyC?apikey=b8blachblahblachc
```

Comment: Can't see how this question (which doesn't even contain an explicit question) is related to Snowflake.  The [snowflake-datawarehouse] tag should be removed.